# Nginx stetting with satisfy any; returns 404 error

Tags: linux, nginx

I want to use basic restriction for nginx , then want to exclude for `/api`

I did this setting. however when accessing /api, 404 returns.

Where am I wrong?

```
server {
    listen      80;
    server_name host;
    charset     utf-8;
 
    location / {
        auth_basic "Restricted";
        auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;

        location /api {
            satisfy any;
            allow   all;
        }
        proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:8011/;
        include     /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass_header X-XSRF-TOKEN;
    }
}
```